# In Sass how can I set a variable to the if statement I created?

Tags: function, variables, sass

Below is the function I'm using:

```
@function set-hover-color($color) {
  @if true {
    @return darken($color, 10%);
  } @else {
    @return lighten($color, 10%)
  }
}
```

I would to be able to set it to true of false like below:

```
$color: false;
```

Comment: Why would you want a color variable to have the value of false? What use would that be?

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Hey @JakeParis thanks for commenting.  I would like to set the function to true or false with a variable.

Comment: What would setting the function to true or false (whatever that means) accomplish?  You seem to understand how to use variables and how to pass variables to functions, so its unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: Hey @cimmanon I appreciate you getting back to me. Its difficult for me to explain because I’m new to sass. I want to keep my functions separate from my config file. So I want t be able change the function to true or false without editing the function.

Comment: You still have not clarified where the problem is.  You don't know how to create a variable that contains a Boolean (true or false)?  You don't know how to use variables in if-statements?

Comment: @cimmanon no I don't. I found this

// Set a variable to run the if statement against
$boolean: true !default

=simple-mixin
  if $boolean
    debug "$boolean is #{$boolean}"
    display: block
  else
    debug "$boolean is #{$boolean}"
    display: none

.some-selector
  +simple-mixin

but don't know how to apply 

darken($color, 10%) and lighten($color, 10%)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for.  **Note:** I renamed the color var to "darken" as i think it makes more sense in this case

```
$darken : true;

@function set-hover-color($color) {
  @if $darken {
     @return darken($color, 10%);
  } @else {
     @return lighten($color, 10%)
  }
};
```

Another option could be to pass in that variable as a second argument. eg:

```
@function set-hover-color($color,$darken) {
  @if $darken {
     @return darken($color, 10%);
  } @else {
     @return lighten($color, 10%)
  }
};
```

Usage :

```
$color : #ddd;

#example{

   color : $color,

   &:hover{

     color : set-hover-color($color,true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for.